# How to use JSON oEmbed specifications in PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to post a photo to the microblogging service Alpha.App.net with OAuth 2.0, PHP and cURL and I need to use the **JSON oEmbed specification** for it.

Below is what I tried but it results in an error response:

> "Bad Request: 'annotations': Must be a list"

```
function sendMessage()
{
$postData = array(
 'text' => "test",
'annotations' => array('type' => 'net.app.core.oembed',
  'version' => '1.0',
        'type' => 'photo',
        'width' => 240,
        'height' => 160,
        'title' => 'ZB8T0193',
        'url' => 'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3123/2341623661_7c99f48bbf_m.jpg',
        'author_name' => 'Bees',
        'author_url' => 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/',
        'provider_name' => 'Flickr',
        'provider_url' => 'http://www.flickr.com/',
        'embeddable_url' => 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2341623661/')
);


$ch = curl_init('https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Bearer '.'0123456789',      
'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));
```

This is the original JSON from the [docs](https://github.com/appdotnet/object-metadata/blob/master/annotations/net.app.core.oembed.md):

```
{
    "type": "net.app.core.oembed",
    "value": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "type": "photo",
        "width": 240,
        "height": 160,
        "title": "ZB8T0193",
        "url": "http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3123/2341623661_7c99f48bbf_m.jpg",
        "author_name": "Bees",
        "author_url": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/",
        "provider_name": "Flickr",
        "provider_url": "http://www.flickr.com/",
        "embeddable_url": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2341623661/"
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to make it a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pack your annotations into another array like *'annotations' => array(array(...))* example is at below:

```
$postData = array(
 'text' => "test",
'annotations' => array(array('type' => 'net.app.core.oembed',
  'version' => '1.0',
        'type' => 'photo',
        'width' => 240,
        'height' => 160,
        'title' => 'ZB8T0193',
        'url' => 'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3123/2341623661_7c99f48bbf_m.jpg',
        'author_name' => 'Bees',
        'author_url' => 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/',
        'provider_name' => 'Flickr',
        'provider_url' => 'http://www.flickr.com/',
        'embeddable_url' => 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2341623661/'))
);
```

And send the request again. I guess they accepts multiple image submit at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an idea how to upload an image to app.net with PHP?